# Firebase - Remove project on Firebase affect Google Play?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-play

I am new to the app publishing stuffs. Following, I have only one app that is published on Google Play and uses Firebase for Push Notification purpose.

Following, I removed my project from Firebase. After that, they sent me an email which make me quite confuse:

Dear Developer,

Your Google Cloud project `project-name` was shut down on March 03, 2020 7:05:44 AM UTC. Shut-down projects and the data stored in them may be recovered for a limited time before the projects are permanently deleted.

If you’d like to recover your project, you must cancel the project’s permanent deletion before April 02, 2020 7:05:44 AM UTC. To recover your shut-down project:

1. Visit the Resources pending deletion page.
2. Select the project you want to recover, and click Restore.
3. In the confirmation dialog, click Restore.

If you take no action by April 02, 2020 7:05:44 AM UTC, you will be unable to recover your project.

If you have any questions, please visit Google Cloud Platform Resource Manager Documentation or contact Google Cloud Platform Support.

Cordially,
The Google Cloud Platform Team

If I take no action and let my project permanently delete by Google, will Google removes my app on Google Play? Or will Google make any affects on my app?

Please help me out. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the removal of a Firebase or Google Cloud project doesn't affect the publication of any app that was added to the project.  The app might stop working if it's access resources in the project, but it will still be visible in the Play store.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Can you please explain more details about the `access resources in the project`? In my case, I ONLY use Firebase for Push Notification, I guess there is no resource access, is that right?

Comment: Sure, as long as you don't want to send messages to your app any more, this won't be a problem.